# What is the best way to fetch email id from group of words?

Tags: android, string

I am getting group of words as output, is there any way to fetch email id's from that group.
My output will be like this.

Lakshman Kumar,D/no:45/24/d4,USA,Android app devoloper,lakshman@gmail.com

Comment: split your value by coma(,) and get your string

Comment: I am getting that output through scanning a visiting card I am able to split the value by coma but i am not able to fetch exact word that I want because I am getting random outputs in some outputs mail id will be in second position in some it will be in 4th position is there any way to fetch the mail id where ever it may be in my output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .

```
 String response = "Lakshman Kumar,D/no:45/24/d4,USA,Android app devoloper,lakshman@gmail.com";
 String[] strings = response.split(",");
 String email = strings[strings.length - 1];
 Log.e("TAG", email);
```

**NOTE**

- Use `split` in your code
- Use `strings[strings.length - 1]` to get value of email

Answer (score 0):

If there are one or more email addresses, split the text and match the pattern of email as below:

```
String[] tokens = yourText.split(",");
for (String token : tokens) {
    if (Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(token).matches()) {
        String email = token;
        //use this email
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use regex for fetching email id from text like this

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}\\b",
    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher("your text will be here ");
    Set<String> emails = new HashSet<String>();
    while(matcher.find()) {
         emails.add(matcher.group());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure that "@" will always be used only inside email addresses, you could do this:

```
String output = "Lakshman Kumar,D/no:45/24/d4,USA,Android app devoloper,lakshman@gmail.com";
public String  getEmail(){

    // Splitting your output by ','
    String[] splittedOutput = output.split(",");

    for (String s : splittedOutput){

        // Checking to see if '@' exists in string
        if (s.indexOf("@") >= 0){
            return s;
        }
    }

    return "email not found";
}
```